# C#: How to work with IPMI va C#?

Tags: c#, .net

There is few info about IPMI(Intelligent Platform Management Interface) in internet. Most solutions use low-level code in C\C++ (for Linux). So, is there any high-level library in C#, that can call IPMI functions? Thanks.
UPD: i need to call requests to remote computer with BMC controller.

Comment: That is the question you should ask in google.

Comment: There are IPMI-Classes implemented in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390891(v=vs.85).aspx
But I don't know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: But "ipmiutil" tool works without installing drivers or using WMI

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following MSDN Link for a lead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390891(v=vs.85).aspx

You can make use of WMI and WINRM. U can use PInvoke to access unmanaged APIs in C#.

Comment: i know about use PInvoke to access unmanaged APIs in C#, but i need unmanaged dll + description of methods. All source codes  int internet is on C/C++ for LINUX.